# how to do division in python without decimal points

Tags: python, integer

if I use **integer** type cast conversion technique then it doesn't work for large numbers like **12630717197566440063**

I got wrong answer in some cases like below in python 3

```
a =12630717197566440063;
print(a)
temp = a/10
print(int(temp))
```

Then I am getting **1263071719756644096** as a answer instead of **1263071719756644006**

Comment: `temp = a // 10`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `//` (floor division) operator:

```py
temp = a//10
print(temp)
```